# Cakephp 2.7: Pagination Numbers set next and prev rel?

Tags: cakephp

how can I set here

```
echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator' => '', 'tag'=>'li'));
```

the rel="next" and rel="prev" information?

And how about this:

```
echo $this->Paginator->meta();
```

How can I make changes to this?
As Google Docs says it is better to use http:// urls?
When I use this meta() the links look like this:

```
<link href="/objects/search" rel="prev"/>
<link href="/objects/search?page=3" rel="next"/>
```